# Django correct method to insert external css framework like Blueprint css into view

Tags: django, django-views

What is the best method to insert external css into view?

Should I do this :

```
   class Media:
       css = (settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX + 'button.css',)
```

Or I directly insert them into html template.

Comment: A view is a function, 'external css' could mean a lot, I think you need more context. Can you expand on the question?

Answer (score 0):

From the context it seems that you're trying to insert CSS into a `ModelAdmin`, in which case your method is definitely correct and is the recommended one.

I would only touch the admin templates if you actually need to override part of them with new markup.

Comment: I am not doing it at ModelAdmin, I am creating a custom view in admin.